# React-Native: Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module

Tags: ios, react-native

In React-Native 0.29 and 0.30. 
When I running on iOS device using the offline bundle, always got Error information below:

> Unhandled JS Exception: Module RCTLog is not a registered callable module.
> RCTFatal + 124
>   -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatalException:stack:exceptionId:] + 584
>    + 144
>    + 296
>    + 68
>   -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 1684
>   -[RCTBatchedBridge _handleRequestNumber:moduleID:methodID:params:] + 712
> __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.452 + 1144
>   ...

Bundle with:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./Example/index.ios.jsbundle --assets-dest ./Example/ --verbose
```

Dose any one got the same issue, how can I fix it, Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Add `var RCTLog = require('RCTLog');` to index.ios.js

Its actually a bug https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8663

Answer (score 1):

That's how I resolved it.

Terminate your metro bundler > `react-native link` > `react-native run-ios`

It was not bundling because of some errors which are not showing into the emulator but just bundling was failed. After I re-bundled the package from starting, so it displayed me the error and then I resolved them, then the error is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

Do you import React in the index.ios.js file?

Comment: Yes, imported it. Everything is fine when I running with online bundle, but not in offline bundle.

Comment: Upgraded to RN 0.31.